# Phalcon Session Adapter? Is it safe?

Tags: php, mysql, mongodb, session, phalcon

Im a little worried about using the session adapter provided by Phalcon. In the documentation it says "This adapter store sessions in plain files", does this mean it stores the session data on the visitors computer or the app host?

Also is this method of storing login information safe? Should i use the default session adapter or should i use something more along the lines of storing the session in MySQL , REDIS, Memcache or maybe Mongo...

Comment: Link to docs -> http://docs.phalconphp.com/en/latest/api/Phalcon_Session_Adapter_Files.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Safe is not normally about whether it is stored in a database or not (mostly since databases can actually be easier to get into than the file system these days) but whether or not the data on disk is stored in a secure manner, i.e. encryption/hashing.

The default adapter stores the sessions within the servers `/tmp` or `C:\temp` normally.

Of course 99.99% of the time you shouldn't store extremely sensitive information that would require encryption in the session, in fact in some countries (the UK) it is against ISO standards to store sensitive information like that for pro-longed periods of time within a session object. Remember that sessions are not impervious, they can be hi-jacked and are all the time even with the added safe guards; there are only so many precautions you can take against something which directly touches the end user (remember that PHP will store session id within cookies and most validation for restoring a session is cookie based).

You should try and make it so that your sessions can be stored in a cookie, since that is the only roughly safe session at the end of the day; one where it doesn't matter if it's data is seen publicly.